# How to Represent JSON response in a table column wise

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the following code to receive a json as response and represent them in a table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var settings = {
            "async" : true,
            "crossDomain" : true,
            "url" : "Parse",
            "method" : "GET",
            "headers" : {
                "content-type" : "application/json"
            },
            "processData" : false
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function(jsnData) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(jsnData);
            for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
                var j=0;
                var trd="";
                trd +="<tr>";
                trd+="<td>"
                + obj[i].word
                trd+= " </td>";
                trd+="<td>"
                + "<select class='input-small'><option value=''>"+obj[i].senses+"</option></select>";//obj[i].senses
                trd+= " </td>";
                trd+="</tr>";


                $('#userdata tr:last').after(trd);
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

The `userdata`  is the id o the table I am using to feed this json response.

The Json format is

```
[
{
"word": "play",
"senses": ["n1","n2","n3"]
},


 {
"word": "play1",
"senses": ["m1","m2","m3"]
```

}`,
  {
    "word": "play2",
    "senses": ["j1","k2","l3"]
  },
  {
    "word": "play3",
    "senses": ["x","ny","z"]
  },
  {
    "word": "play4",
    "senses": ["p","q","r"]
  }
]`

In my table there are two columns,One for word and one for senses,but I want the senses column as drop down.I am getting the output as follow,
[image]

As you can see,the Option column which I want to use to represent senses,showing the senses for the respected word in one line,e.g. for word `play` its senses are showed as `n1,n2,n3`.I want them to be shown as drop down,i.e. for for word `play`,drop down values will be `n1 n2 and n3` for word `play1`,drop down values will be `m1 m2 and m3`.

HTML code

```
    <table id="userdata" border="2">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Word</b></td>
            <td><b>Options</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried hard but was not been able to do it in desired way.any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use unnecessary tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
 + "<select class='input-small'>";
 for(var k=0; i <obj[i].senses.length;k++){
  trd+="<option value='"+obj[i].senses[k]+"'>"+obj[i].senses[k]+"</option>";
 }
trd+="</select>";
```

Comment: for(var k=0; i <obj[i].senses.length;k++){,the  condition check is k <obj[i].senses.length.It worked.